# Jasper reports - iReport - page number variable doesn't work

Tags: jasper-reports

I have to prepare a letter in which I require a 40 mm page header for first page and 20mm page header for all other pages except the first page. So I've created 2 page headers.

I want to hide/show the page headers based on the page number. 
But when I write the following print when expression, it doesn't work.

```
$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals("1")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check what the type of $V{PAGE_NUMBER} is... (I think it is **java.lang.Integer**)

The method you choose return a boolean an a PrintWhenExpression should return a **java.lang.Boolean**, so you need to instantiate one.

Try :

```
new Boolean($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals("1"))
```

It should work... To improve your test, I think that it is better to make a int comparison (a Java specialist should confirm that)

```
new Boolean($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue() == 1)
```

The other manipulation you might have to do is specifying the whole object name (I don't know how JasperReport deals with import)

```
new java.lang.Boolean($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue() == 1)
```